# RestartSource masking the materialized value for the wrapped source?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am modifying an existing stream graph by adding some retry logic around various functionality.  One of those pieces is the source, which in this case happens to be a kafka `Consumer.committableSource` from the alpakka kafka connector.  Downstream, the graph is expecting a type of `Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AnyRef], Control]`, but when I wrap the committable source in a `RestartSource` I end up with `Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AnyRef], NotUsed]`

I tried adding `(Keep.both)` on the end, but ended up with a compile time error.  Here are the two examples for reference:

```
val restartSource: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AnyRef], NotUsed] = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
  minBackoff = 3.seconds,
  maxBackoff = 60.seconds,
  randomFactor = .2
) {() => Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, subscription)}

val s: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AnyRef], Control] = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, subscription)
```

Comment: Don't you just want `Keep.left`?

Comment: @erip where would I put that?  If I put it after the factory `...subscription)}(Keep.left)` I get `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.kafka.ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String,Object],akka.NotUsed] does not take parameters`

Comment: After you've materialized the stream. `restartSource.viaMat(...)(Keep.left)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, and as discussed in this currently open [ticket](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/24771), the materialized value of the original `Source` is not exposed in the return value of the wrapping `RestartSource`. To get around this, try using [`mapMaterializedValue`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mapMaterializedValue%5BMat2%5D(f:Mat=%3EMat2):Source.this.ReprMat%5BOut,Mat2%5D) (disclaimer: I didn't test the following):

```
val restartSource: Source[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, AnyRef], Control] = {
  var control: Option[Control] = None

  RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
    minBackoff = 3.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 60.seconds,
    randomFactor = .2
  ) { () =>
    Consumer
      .committableSource(consumerSettings, subscription)
      .mapMaterializedValue { c =>
        control = Some(c)
      }
  }
  .mapMaterializedValue(_ => control)
  .collect { case Some(c) => c }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `preMaterialize` the `Source` which will yield the `Control` like so:

```
Pair<Consumer.Control, Source<ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset, NotUsed>> controlSourcePair =
    origSrc.preMaterialize(materializer);

Source<ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset, NotUsed> source =
    RestartSource.withBackoff(
        Duration.ofSeconds(1),
        Duration.ofSeconds(10),
        0.2,
        20,
        controlSourcePair::second);
source
    .toMat(Committer.sink(CommitterSettings.create(system)
        .withMaxBatch(1)), Keep.both())
    .mapMaterializedValue(pair -> 
        Consumer.createDrainingControl(
            new Pair<>(controlSourcePair.first(), pair.second())))
    .run(materializer);
```

Apologies for not providing you with the Scala equivalent.